# WPF setting dynamic height to DataGrid and using Horizontal GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, gridsplitter

I am creating an application containing grid with 2 rows. It has a DataGrid in a top row and description area in the bottom row. Now I have 2 problems:

1. If I do not set the height of the DataGrid specifically, loading approximately more than 100 rows takes longer time. If rows are too many, it takes forever. If I set the height, it loads any number of rows instantly and shows the vertical scroll bar. How can I set the DataGrid to fit into the first row without specifying the height/maxheight properties?
2. I want to use Horizontal GridSplitter so that I can resize each row. However, it does not work after DataGrid is loaded with rows. It works before loading the rows.

Below is My code:

```
<ScrollViewer >
    <Grid>
        

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        
        <GridSplitter Panel.ZIndex="1"
            ResizeDirection="Rows" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Height="2" 
                      Background="#c0c0c0" />

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">

                <DataGrid 
                    Margin="10" 
                    Name="EventLogsDataGrid" 
                    IsReadOnly="False" 
                    SelectionChanged="EventLogsDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserSortColumns="False"
                    EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                    EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                    ColumnWidth="*"
                    MaxHeight="500"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    CanUserAddRows="False"
                    CanUserResizeRows="True"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    CanUserDeleteRows="False" />


</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">

<Label Content="Description" Margin="5 0 0 0"/>

</StackPanel>

</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have tried setting the DataGrid HorizontalAlignment to Stretch. I have also tried to use the binding to set the height of the DataGrid to the parent element but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A StackPanel grows as large as its child elements want, which means that your DataGrid expands to is maximum height. So simply remove the StackPanel and add the DataGrid as direct child of the Grid. Also remove the other StackPanel, since it is also pointless.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter .../>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ... />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you Clemens for the quick answer. Initially I did not use StackPanel and had the same exact code as you posted. What I really want is "How do I resize the DataGrid using the GridSplitter?", I am unable to do that. My DataGrid is of fixed size because of the problem number 1 but even if I remove the maxheight, I cannot resize the DataGrid after it loads the data. I see the parent Grid Row is resizing and that is causing the vertical scrollbar to grow however DataGrid stays of same height.

Comment: You should also remove the outer Scrollviewer because its child Grid will as well grow as large as it wants.

Comment: <Grid>
        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter 
        Grid.Row="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Height="5"
        ResizeDirection="Rows"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Foreground="Black"
    />

    <DataGrid Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        
    </DataGrid>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="description" />

</Grid>

Comment: This is my updated code and I cannot still make my DataGrid resize dynamically. Apologies for the formatting.

Comment: Please don't apologize for formatting, edit your question instead. And explain why there is `Height="100"`, `Grid.RowSpan="3"` and `VerticalAlignment="Top"` on the DataGrid. That does all not make any sense.

Comment: I was doing everything wrong, you basically have solved my problem with all the information you provided. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.